# ActionScript 3 Flash CS5 Website: How can I play a fade out animation before the page changes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have created a flash website that navigates by labels on key frames.

How can I have my pages fade in and out when navigating?

This is not an animation question it's an actionscript 3 question.

the navigation code looks like this:

```
aboutbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotohome);

function gotohome(event:MouseEvent):void

{gotoAndStop("home");}
```

With entire pages on a single frame over 3 layers. I have 5 main pages and 2 sub-pages within these.

So how can I play a fade out animation before the page changes?

Help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

function gotohome(event:MouseEvent):void{
   var mytween:Tween = new Tween(stage, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
   mytween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, showHome); 

}
function showHome(event:TweenEvent):void{
   new Tween(stage, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
   gotoAndStop("home");
}
```

Comment: the compiler doesn't like (event:TweenEvent)

Comment: @AaronCox add `import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a white background movieclip fade_Mc. Place it over the stage.

So, the code would look like this:

```
aboutbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotohome);

function gotohome(event:MouseEvent):void
{

gotoAndStop("home");
 fade_Mc.visible = true 
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut)

}

function fadeOut(e:Event)
{

    fade_Mc.alpha -= 0.5 // change this value as per the speed of fade required

    if ( fade_Mc.alpha <=0 )
    {
     fade_Mc.visible = false
     fade_Mc.alpha = 1 ;
     removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut)
     }

}
```